Alternative orientation of android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" is deprecated in Android Java and i am trying to use  <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item> in app theme and also tried to use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) in activity but the problem using these is that while navigation to Activity its Open in Landscape and its turns to portrait.
Is there any option to restrict the screen in portrait or landscape?

android:screenOrientation="portrait" is not deprecated in Android Java. Google would prefer that you not use it and instead support landscape. They do steer you in this direction via a warning in Android Studio, one that you can suppress using tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi". That is not a deprecation warning, and no aspect of the screenOrientation attribute is documented as being deprecated.
